# Question on sets of numbers in "$8_3$ in $PG(2,q)$"...

Tags: projective-geometry, cyclic-groups

I was doing brute force numerical experiments and [googled](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%223%2C4%2C9%2C11%20mod%2021%22) some of the results. Surprsingly I found the paper mentioned in the title: ["$8_3$ in $PG(2,q)$"](https://epdf.pub/8-3-in-pg-2-q.html). In there, out of the blue, sets of numbers are presented
$$
\begin{array}{c|rl}
- & \{0,1,3\} &\mod 8 \\
PG(2,3) &\{0,1,3,9\} &\mod 13 \\
PG(2,4) & \{0,3,4,9,11\} &\mod 21 \\
PG(2,q)& ...?
\end{array}
$$
Interestingly all of them were solutions in my brute force numerical search.
Can anyone explain how the following sets of numbers are generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authors of [A-EA-DJ] use such sets, called (relative) difference sets as bases for combinatorial schemes of incidences between points and lines. I recall that a subset $D$ of a group $G$ is called a *difference set* if each non-identity element $g\in G$ can be uniquely written as $g = xy^{−1}$ for some elements $x, y\in D$ [BG]. In 1938 Singer [S] showed that for any prime power $m$ a cyclic group $\Bbb Z_{m_2+m+1}$ contains a difference set of cardinality $m + 1$. He called them *perfect  difference  sets  of  order  $m  + 1$*) and presented the following table

[image]

Thus a set $\{0,1,3\}$ of residues is a difference set for a group $\Bbb Z_7$ but only a relative difference set for a group $\Bbb Z_8$ (in which, for instance, $4$ is not a difference of elements of the set), a set  $\{0,1,3,9\}$ of residues is a difference set for a group $\Bbb Z_{13}$, and both sets $\{0,1,4,14,16\}$ and $\{0,3,4,9,11\}$ of residues is a difference set for a group $\Bbb Z_{21}$ (remark that the set $\{0,3,4,9,11\}$ is an image of the set $\{0,1,4,14,16\}$ under a map $x\mapsto 5x+4$ of a ring $\Bbb Z_{21}$).

*References*

[A-EA-DJ] M.S. Abdul-Elah, M.W. Al-Dhamg, Dieter  Jungnickel, *$8_3$  in $PG (2, q)$*, Arch. math.,  **49** (1987) 141–150.

[BG] Taras Banakh, Volodymyr Gavrylkiv, *[Difference bases in cyclic groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.02631)*.

[S] James Singer, *[A theorem in ﬁnite projective geometry and some applications to number theory](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1990067)*, Trans. amer. math. soc. **43**:3 (1938), 377–385.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you know if this difference approach was/can be extended from $xy^{-1}$ to $x^2y^{-1}z^{-1}$?

Comment: @draks... Yes, I think formally this approach can be extended to such monomials, but they look too specific and I didn’t heard about this extension. As far as I know, usually investigators care about sizes of difference sets and in your case it can be smaller, maybe in some cases of $O(|G|^{1/4})$. If you have a research project related to such sets then I can speak to Banakh and Gavrylkiv and maybe they will help to calculate such sets, write a program, or give a project to their (postgraduate) students.

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you very much for your offer. I'll discuss it with my colleague and come back to you in case...